# Get images height and width in folder using JS before loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering is there any script that before loading accesses all images in a specific folder, parses them to get their appropriate height and width so i would use them later on? This all needs to be done before loading anything into the webpage. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

The only conceivable way I can think of is to make a custom server, either a standard static server with python even, or even better, with nodeJS, then let the server automatically read either

- a list of all of the file names in the folder, and send it to the client, then on the client side, stop the loading with JavaScript until each picture is loaded via ajax, and analyzed by drawing to a canvas, or even just setting it as the source for an `img` element, then waiting for the `onload` event of each, and checking the width and height [not gonna write up a full code example for this but let me know if you need more clarification]
- Load everything on the server side, including a list of all of  the images, and also find some kind of basic image processing library for the server side, for example something like pngjs for nodejs, to get the width and height for each image, after reading it with `fs.readFileSync` to get the raw binary data etc., then after getting the full array of image data with NodeJS, finally (if using `createServer`) call `request.end`.... etc., for your specific web page that is being hosted at

I'm not going to write up a full code example at this time but let me know if more clarification is needed